# Select Previous and Next Business Day in BiqQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table "us_holidays_list" having below data into the table:

| date_id | description |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | New Year''s Day |
| 1/17/2022 | Martin Luther King Day |
| 2/21/2022 | Presidents Day |
| 5/30/2022 | Memorial Day |
| 6/19/2022 | Juneteenth |
| 6/20/2022 | Juneteenth (observed) |
| 7/4/2022 | Independence Day |
| 9/5/2022 | Labor Day |
| 10/10/2022 | Columbus Day |
| 11/11/2022 | Veterans Day |
| 11/24/2022 | Thanksgiving Day |
| 12/25/2022 | Christmas Day |

Now in a select statement we need to get select Previous and Next Business Days by looking into the date values we get from below query in Big query

```sql
select date_sub(boms, interval 0 day) as start_date
from unnest(generate_date_array('2020-01-01', current_date(), interval 1 day)) boms
```

Comment: can you update your post with the expected output table given the provided input one?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
with us_holidays_list as (
  select date '2022-1-1' date_id, "New Year's Day" description union all
  select '2022-1-17', "Martin Luther King Day" union all
  select '2022-2-21', "Presidents Day" union all
  select '2022-5-30', "Memorial Day" union all
  select '2022-6-19', "Juneteenth" union all
  select '2022-6-20', "Juneteenth (observed)" union all
  select '2022-7-4', "Independence Day" union all
  select '2022-9-5', "Labor Day" union all
  select '2022-10-10', "Columbus Day" union all
  select '2022-11-11', "Veterans Day" union all
  select '2022-11-24', "Thanksgiving Day" union all
  select '2022-12-25', "Christmas Day" 
), calendar as (
  select day, not extract(dayofweek from day) in (1,7) isBusinessDay
  from unnest(generate_date_array('2021-12-30', current_date())) day
)
select * from (
  select date_id, description, 
    last_value(qualified_day ignore nulls) over(order by day rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) Previous_Business_Day,
    first_value(qualified_day ignore nulls) over(order by day rows between 1 following and unbounded following) Next_Business_Day
  from (
    select *, if(isBusinessDay and date_id is null, day, null) as qualified_day from calendar
    left join us_holidays_list 
    on date_id = day
    where isBusinessDay or not date_id is null
  )
)
where not date_id is null
```

with output

[image]

Comment: have you tried? did it work for you?

Comment: Hello ,

This approach is worked , not facing another issue how to add this output into another days ??

we are build date Dimension table for 40 years and populate dates with prevois and next business days for all the days .

Comment: Holiday days are 1/1/2022 and 1/17/2022
date_id Previous_Business_Day Next_Business_Day
12/31/2021 12/30/2021 1/3/2022
1/1/2022 12/31/2021 1/3/2022
1/2/2022 12/31/2021 1/18/2022
1/3/2022 12/31/2021 1/4/2022
1/4/2022 1/3/2022 1/5/2022
1/5/2022 1/4/2022 1/6/2022
1/6/2022 1/5/2022 1/7/2022
1/7/2022 1/6/2022 1/10/2022

Comment: 1/8/2022 1/7/2022 1/10/2022
1/9/2022 1/7/2022 1/10/2022
1/10/2022 1/7/2022 1/11/2022
1/11/2022 1/10/2022 1/12/2022
1/12/2022 1/11/2022 1/13/2022
1/13/2022 1/12/2022 1/14/2022
1/14/2022 1/13/2022 1/15/2022
1/15/2022 1/14/2022 1/17/2022
1/16/2022 1/14/2022 1/17/2022
1/17/2022 1/14/2022 1/18/2022